# Doctype IE 8 Issues onload

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, doctype

I have no idea how or why this is happening...

On page load in IE 8 - the site loads with browser mode set to IE 8 ( this is good ) however browser standards are set to IE 7?!?!?

Here is the Doctype used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The site also uses DD_roundies:

[DD_roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/)

I thought this may have been the issue as it is known to be a cause so I updated the script and no luck there.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the XHTML Transitional mode?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```